# sample for gps in android includes feature of tracking

Tags: android, gps

I am very new to Android Development.

- I am in a position to do `R&D` in `GPS system.`
- I found some of samples from here. But that is not clear for me to understand.
- Can any one help me for sample programs for GPS includes features of `Google Map view`, Current location,`GPS` Tracking and path.

Answer (score 1):

I use following Library created by me for tracking GPS Co-Ordinates,

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LocListener implements LocationListener
{
    private static double lat =0.0;
    private static double lon = 0.0;
    private static double alt = 0.0; 
    private static double speed = 0.0;

    public static double getLat()
    {
        return lat;
    }

    public static double getLon() 
    {
        return lon;
    }

    public static double getAlt()
    {
        return alt;
    }

    public static double getSpeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
        alt = location.getAltitude();
        speed = location.getSpeed(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

Using following way you can fetch latitude,longitude details from the above class,

```
String latitude,longitude;

    latitude = String.valueOf( LocListener.getLat() ); 
    longitude = String.valueOf( LocListener.getLon() );
```

for fetching gps you need to give gps permissions, in your AndroidManifest.xml as follows,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```